# Faster determination if two nodes are connected in a graph

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks

In the code below `connectedQ[g_,v1_,v2_]` is a function to check if two nodes `v1` and `v2` in graph `g` are connected or not. 
 `nodepairs1` and `nodepairs2` are two examples of pair of nodes that I want to check.

```
myGraph = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5, 5 <-> 1, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 1, 3 <-> 5}];
nodepairs1 = {{1, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 1}, {2, 1}};
nodepairs2 = {{1, 6}, {6, 5}, {5, 1}, {2, 6}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 9}, {3, 4}};
connectedQ[g_, v1_, v2_] := MemberQ[VertexComponent[g, v1], v2]
```

Next I apply the function to the two pairs of nodes.

```
Apply[And, connectedQ[myGraph, Sequence @@ #]& /@ nodepairs1]
Apply[And, connectedQ[myGraph, Sequence @@ #]& /@ nodepairs2]

(* 
Out[375]= True
Out[376]= False *)
```

Output is `True` if all pairs of nodes are connected and `False` if at least one pair of nodes are not connected.

This code works but it's slow if there are a lot of node pairs to check (hundreds of thousands of pairs). So I'm trying to find a way to make it faster.

One possible way I could think is that returning `False` when it sees a pair which are not connected and not checking the remaining pairs anymore. How would you do this? Or do you have a better idea to do this fast?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Build an association that assigns an index for its connected component to every vertex:

```
a = Association[Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[Rule[#1, #2[[1]]]] &, ConnectedComponents[myGraph]]]
```

Then you can check whether  `v1` and `v2` belong to the same component like this:

```
a[v1] == a[v2]
```

To check many at once, you can use `Lookup`:

```
{v1, v2} = Transpose[nodepairs1];
And @@ MapThread[SameQ, {Lookup[a, v1], Lookup[a, v2]}]

{v1, v2} = Transpose[nodepairs2];
And @@ MapThread[SameQ, {Lookup[a, v1], Lookup[a, v2]}]
```

> True

> False

Using vectorized integer operations instead of `MapThread` can also give you some performance improvement. This is the code:

```
SameQ[Max[Unitize[Subtract[Lookup[a, v1], Lookup[a, v2]]]], 0]
```

OP's `MemberQ`-method looks quite $O(\text{$\#$vertices} \cdot \text{$\#$nodepairs})$-ish if not $O(\text{$\#$vertices}^2 \cdot \text{$\#$nodepairs})$-ish to me.
The algorithmic complexity of my method should be in the ball park of

$$O(\text{$\#$vertices})$$

for computing the components (and the `Association`) and

$$ O(\log(\text{$\#$components}) \cdot \text{$\#$nodepairs})$$

for the lookup.

If your vertex labels are simply the consecutive integers starting from 1, then you can even use a simple packed array as lookup table. The build time is quite a bit faster and the lookup is seems to be two orders of magnitude faster.

Build the lookup table:

```
lookup = 
  Normal[
   SparseArray[
    Join @@ 
     MapIndexed[Thread[Rule[#1, #2[[1]]]] &, 
      ConnectedComponents[G]]]];
```

Do the check:

```
SameQ[Max[Unitize[Subtract[Lookup[a, v1], Lookup[a, v2]]]], 0]
```

Unfortunately, all these approaches do no allow for short-circuiting. This would require loop constructs like `While` in the "hot"part of the code. Since *Mathematica* is an interpreted language, it is not well-suited for such a task. (Although one might be able to tweak, e.g. `NestWhile` to make it work.) However, with the plain array lookup table, we can compile the lookup code:

```
cf = Compile[{{lookup, _Integer, 1}, {nodepairs, _Integer, 2}},
  Block[{bool, i},
   bool = True;
   i = 0;
   While[bool && (i < Length[nodepairs] - 1),
    ++i;
    bool = 
     bool && (Compile`GetElement[nodepairs, i, 1] == 
        Compile`GetElement[nodepairs, i, 2]);
    ];
   bool
   ],
  CompilationTarget -> "C",
  RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
  Parallelization -> True,
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
  ];
```

You would just call it like this:

```
cf[lookup, nodepairs]
```

This would also work (even in parallel), if `nodepairs` were a list of lists of node pairs; then `cf` would thread over the outer list.

Comment: Indeed, igraph's R package represents components not by a list of lists (like Mathematica), but by assigning a component index to each node.

Comment: It is good to note that this approach works only for undirected graphs. Computing a transitive closure may be useful, if memory consuming, for directed graphs.

Answer (score 8):

Nice and simple,

```
ConnectedVerticesQ[graph_,v1_,v2_] := UnsameQ[GraphDistance[graph,v1,v2],Infinity]
```

In my tests this is faster than the OP's `connectedQ`. It also has the advantage of not needing to precompute the connected components in a lookup table which you then have to keep track of.

Answer (score 7):

```
b = Association @ KeyValueMap[Thread @* Rule] @  Map[First] @ 
    PositionIndex @ ConnectedComponents @ myGraph;
```

An alternative way to use `Lookup`:

```
allConnectedQ = SameQ @@ Lookup[Union @@ #] @ b &;

allConnectedQ @ nodepairs1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
allConnectedQ @ nodepairs2
```

> ```
> False
> ```